# How to automate the explode process in wildfly deployment?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, wildfly, war, explode

**Issue**:
Though the deployment is success, web application is not up and running. It is giving ‘Not Found’ error message inside html tags when we hit the URL in the browser.

**Note**: Application war is deployed using the command mentioned below.
nohup sh standalone.sh -b=0.0.0.0 -bmanagement=0.0.0.0 &

**Workaround**:
Only if we explode the war using explode option in Wildlfy console, application will work.

Can someone please suggest how to automate the explode process or any other way to bring up the application?